# Integral question - $\int\frac{\sqrt{\tan(x)}}{{\cos^2(x)}}dx$

Tags: integration

Integral question - $$\int\frac{\sqrt{\tan(x)}}{{\cos^2(x)}}dx$$
I see that $\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$ is the derivative of $\tan(x)$ so I set $t =  \tan(x)$? or the whole square?

Thanks!

Comment: $\tan'x=\sec^2x$

Comment: Just $\tan(x)$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to set just $\tan(x) = t$. If you set $\tan(x) = t$, we get that $\sec^2(x) dx = dt$, i.e., $\dfrac{dx}{\cos^2(x)} = dt$. Hence, we get
$$\int \dfrac{\sqrt{\tan(x)}}{\cos^2(x)}dx = \int \sqrt{t} dt$$
I trust you can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for a derivable function $\,f(x)\,$ , we have that

$$\int\sqrt{f(x)}\;f'(x)\;dx=\frac23f(x)\sqrt{f(x)} + C$$